# not setting the ng-options select to the predefined ng-model results

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a value fed in and want it preselected in the select dropdown. The complication is that the model is an object not a simple string. I tried using track by but it does not seem to solve the issue... Maybe you can help?

Let's assume the models in the javascript when the controller loads:

```
$scope.condition = {name: 'blah', value: '{"id":2,"value":"Monthly Flyer"}' }
$scope.options = [
    {"id":1,"value":"Winter Catalog"},
    {"id":2,"value":"Monthly Flyer"},
    {"id":3,"value":"Sample Catalog"},
    {"id":4,"value":"Senior Living"},
    ...]
```

Notice how the second one is the same looking object as the first... however, technically it would have a different object reference so

`angular.toJson($scope.condition) === angular.toJson(options[1])` is `true`
BUT
`$scope.condition === options[1]` is `false`

Here's the code

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="condition.value"
        ng-options="opt as (opt.value + ' [' + opt.id + ']')
            for opt in options.picklistOptions track by opt.id"></select>
```

Why do you think it's not loading?

Comment: You mean `$scope.condition = {}; $scope.condition.value = $scope.options.picklistOptions[0];`? (For preselecting the first option)

Comment: yeah sorry I excluded an ng-repeat before where I have ng-repeat="for condition in ...". you can assume it's $scope.condition and $scope.options though.

Comment: Wait - I don't understand, are you trying to set it from the view? Are you doing it by using `ng-init="condition.value = options.picklistOptions[0]"`?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo, how are you getting the `condition.value`? The **whole** object?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo Try changing the ngRepeat to `ng-options="opt.id as ....."` (Note the `opt.id`!). And set `$scope.condition.value =  = 2;` To reference for the `{"id":2,"value":"Monthly Flyer"},` object in the select (Note that now `$scope.condition.value` will reference to the **id** property in the collection, and not to a specific object)

Comment: hi @AlonEitan I think your suggestion would would but then I would have to strip some information when preparing the condition value because otherwise it is an object and it would not resolve to match `option.id`. btw in your suggestion are you saying to keep or remove the `track by` clause?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo Not sure I understand what you mean with the `condition.value` - It will not be an object, but the current ID of the selected option, BTW you should remove the `track by` clause if using my suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think you have an object saved somewhere and you want to select the `<option>` based on this.

Then, if I'm correct you just made ​​the mistake of having placed the ng-model as `condition.value` instead of just `condition`.

See it working:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.options = {};
      $scope.options.picklistOptions = [  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "value":"Winter Catalog"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "value":"Monthly Flyer"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "value":"Sample Catalog"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "value":"Senior Living"
         }
      ];

      $scope.condition = {
        "id":2,
        "value":"Monthly Flyer"
      };         
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="condition" ng-options="opt as (opt.value + ' [' + opt.id + ']') for opt in options.picklistOptions track by opt.id"></select>
  <hr>
  <span ng-bind="condition | json"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd have prefered to keep the logic with the ng-options DSL but this'll probably do the job as a work around!

Comment: @ThinkBonobo, can you explain a bit more what do you want? Maybe I can help more.. First, how is the object that you're getting from your server-side?

Comment: Sure, let's say I get a json that I save as condition.value (object), and I get another json that pulls in the options (list of objects). now I want those options to load in a select box but I want what I have as condition.value to be selected by default.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo, please, take a look on my answer now and let me know if it's correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Although your direct answer was not the solution it led me to the right direction and helped me find the problem. The problem did indeed lie in the `condition.value`. Basically my `condition.value` was a json string instead of an object. I did the conversion `angular.fromJson` and things seemed to work now.

Comment: Absolutely. I have edited the question to reflect my problem with the updated info which I didn't notice before your help. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
  $scope.listOptions = [
    {id:1,value:"Winter Catalog"},
    {id:2,value:"Monthly Flyer"},
    {id:3,value:"Sample Catalog"},
    {id:4,value:"Senior Living"}
  ];
    
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">  </script>
   </head>
<body ng-controller="Controller">
  
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="obj_options" ng-options="item as item.value for item in listOptions"></select>
  
  <span>{{obj_options.value}}</span>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Guilherme, I didn't downvote you and I'm not sure why the person who downvoted you did, but, although your answer is a great example of using ng-options basically, my question is about having that `obj_options` value preset from a distinct object.